# Windows Search Service: Getting Text snips

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search, windows-search

Using Windows Search Service I query and get documents' meta data like `ItemName`.

Is there a way to get a text `snip of the text` that was found so I can show context to the user?

```
        string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO.1;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
         string Query = @"SELECT System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.Title, System.ItemUrl FROM SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file:c:\Index' and FREETEXT('Happy')";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
           ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its old but can be useful for someone who has the same question.

Please Use System.Search.AutoSummary which gives first 1000 characters from a document.